# How does frontend apps hide backend API call URL's?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend, react-fullstack

I'm fairly new to the webdev. I have a React frontend built with Vite, and a Node.js backend that uses MongoDB. I finished my little project and when It came to deploy it to my Linux server, I got confused about how to handle API calls.

Is there any way to hide API URL's on frontend apps? Because everything is done in client side, and frontend is basically an interface between user and backend, that should be impossible. But how does for example, big companies like Facebook handle this? If I go to Facebook and inspect the code, can I find the exact IP and API address that facebook backend serves me the posts? Or are there any tricks to make this more secure? What are the industry standards are on this topic?

Comment: the API that the client accesses to get data is what companies decided should be accessible so the security concerns are dealt with before the API exists

Comment: You probably want to learn about authentication and authorization, not about IP address obfuscation ("security by obscurity").

Comment: **You cannot hide the APIs that a web page uses.**  They are publicly accessible in the web page or via development tools that look at what the web page does.  You handle security issues by authenticating users and detecting abusive use of the APIs on the server and banning those user accounts.  You don't handle security on the web by hiding anything.

Comment: *If I go to Facebook and inspect the code, can I find the exact IP and API address that facebook backend serves me the posts?* - yes

Comment: Thank you so all so much. So there is no way other than to just put my servers IP on the fetch function for example. What I should think about is not if people can find my endpoints, but how do I restricr them of abusing it.

Answer (score 0):

The interface between your web application in the browser and your backend service is HTTP(s). There are HTTP verbs such as GET, POST, DELETE, etc. You can pass argument or information to your backend services via query parameters which are visible in the URL, or you can send it in the body of a request. An HTTP POST, for example would have a body that is not seen or viewable unless the end user made specific effort to view it.

Comment: Thanks! I already have a basic API. My concern was that is it the best practice to just put my servers IP and endpoints on fetch requests, but I think that's fine, and impossible to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to make API calls completely unreadable from the browser.

However, there are a few techniques you can use to make it more difficult for attackers to understand and exploit the API calls.

- Obfuscation: You can use 'js-obfuscator'
- Encryption: You can use 'crypto-js'
- Build tools: You can use 'webpack' or 'gulp'